# ffmpeg.wasm to transcode multi-bitrate HLS or DASH?

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, webassembly, hls.js

my website allows users to upload videos but my servers cant handle the traffic and the budget is low. i heard about webassembly and i have been looking to see if i can transcode on client-side and then upload the hls files to my server.

I cannot find any documentation about hls on ffmpeg.wasm is it even possible.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is transcode your video files to mpeg ts and once it's done you can initiate the upload. I'm not sure if you can generate play list with ffmpeg.wasm. But before uploading you can write your packager to package the encoded files into m3u8

Comment: But is there a tool that can do this for me on client side

Comment: I think the tool is ffmpeg.wasm you want to use right? if you are looking for creating hls with ffmpeg you can look here: https://ottverse.com/hls-packaging-using-ffmpeg-live-vod/

and here is the link how you can run the command using ffmpeg.wasm: https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm#usage